# Prevent wearables from smelling like body odor

Tags: smell

I wear a Fitbit all day, every day - including obviously when I work out, given that's largely what it's meant to track!

Recently I've noticed its started smelling like, well, BO. Both the band (which I'm guessing is rubber of some sort?) and the actual electronic "bit" that sits inside it.

Other than not wearing it when I work out, is there anything I can do to prevent or "fix" this smell?

Comment: Thanks to those who have answered so far. Great suggestions. It will take me a bit to test it out and see what works but I'll be sure to come back here and accept an answer if it has solved the problem!

Answer (score 4):

Source of odor is sweat/dust, so combat that:-

(preventive)

1. Use bit of dusting powder on your wrist before wearing it. Perfumed talcum powder works too.
2. antiperspirant deodorant stick or if not that then spray would help too
3. perfume could help too

(Fixes)

1. Clean with mild soap
2. mouthwash works too as long as you don't mind minty flavor
3. toothpaste works well for metal straps, not sure for rubber ones

Answer (score 3):

I clean my apple watch band with disinfectant hand soap. It doesn't damage the strap and cleans well. I clean the watch itself with screen cleaner, since mine has alcohol in it as well.

I do this every 2-3 days and it keeps it free from BO and discolouration.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add this: don't get leather on your skin. Because it's permeable and can absorb sweat, it can hold onto body odors for a long time and is hard to clean.

Also, periodically dip the wearables in alcohol to kill off the germs which cause body odor.
(Note that I'm not responsible if the alcohol damages the rubber seals or anything else)